# Помогите будущему студенту выбрать, куда идти

Tags: математика, информатика

У меня малой должен подать в течение 6 дней заявление на поступление в студенты. Он проходит по баллам, так что надо только выбрать, куда. Он уже решил, что идет в киевский универ, но у него два варианта - информатика на факультете кибернетики, с дальним прицелом на проблемы ИИ, и второй - компьютерная математика на мехмате, с прицелом в Big Data. Уже совсем решился на кибфак, но тут позвонила декан мехмата (он на мехмате победитель олимпиады в этом году) и зазывала лично, соблазняя Big Data и компьютерной безопасностью. Малой реально завис... А я и не очень хорошо с этими вещами знаком, да и учился давно и не этому... и потом - родителя всегда слушают меньше всего :) Сам он, увы, в школе этими проблемами интересовался мало, так что собственного опыта и знаний у него для четкого решения не хватает, а мне не хочется, чтобы его решение опиралось на факторы типа "да все пацаны с класса пошли на кибернетику - ну и я с ними за компанию!"...

Если можно - тезисно изложите, чем хорош и интересен с вашей точки зрения тот или иной выбор.

Comment: бакалавриат или уже мага?

Comment: @handowl Бакалаврат, после школы

Comment: Что-то у меня есть сомнения, что там реально чему то толковому в IT учат. 20 лет назад я учился на кибфаке, хорошо преподавали фундаментальные вещи, более менее новые/мейнстримовые (в то время вещи), как я уже сейчас вижу, были на очень плохом уровне. Большие сомнения, что там стало лучше. Хотя преподы по фундаментальным вещам все еще преподают. 20 лет назад нужные вещи учили сами.

Comment: отчасти согласен с @RomanKonoval, сам только окончил, профита не сильно много, однако для старта неплохо совсем(правда не Киев). Мне кажется, лучше идти на кибернетику. Как уже было сказано, базовые вещи преподаются, может и Big Data зацепят, так что тут только в плюсе

Comment: Перечитал, что написал, и вижу, что важный момент не передал и все грустно выглядит. Я очень доволен, что учился на кибфаке. Дало это очень много, но нужно понимать, что ожидать.

Comment: опять же берут не прям, но по верхам отовсюду, но по опыту знаю, что задел на ИИ и правда есть. Биг Дата - это же частично тоже к машинному обучению, однако, на прям на биг дата нацеливания не было вообще. Я так понимаю, что начинаешь разбираться в машинном обучении, немного окунаешься и в биг дату, но наоборот - точно нет

Comment: я кстати учился на фундаментальной информатике, ближе к кибернетике. Но успел до этого поучиться на мехмате, вообще ноль программирования, ноль информатике (о чем речь, нас семестр учили, что такое ftp-сервер, и как работать с командой строкой в винде на примере трех команд, там не было даже паскаля, который был в школе)))

Comment: Тезисно.
1. ИИ - сфера шире и иногда включает BD
2. Мехмат для программирования - не особо
3. В целом знания и там, и там - одинаковые: матан, обж, фра, алгебра, ооп и чуть-чуть AI/BD

НО
Комп. науки - это вещь, если грамотно преподать. И если компьютерная математика будет с уклоном на них, то можно и подумать над мехматом.

Comment: А я вот что то совсем запутался. Почему математика имеет прицел на биг дату и безопасность. В безопасности на математику завязано только шифрование. В бигдате разумеется то же есть разделы, в которых используется серьезная математика, но так же очень много разделов которые арифметикой обойдутся и там нужны другие знания. А вот ИИ наоборот без математики никуда. По моему логичней бы выглядело математика - ИИ, информатика/кибернетика - бигдата и безопасность. Так что думаю нужно рассматривать дополнительные вводные, вроде изучаемых предметов, а то названия факультетов слишком обобщенны

Comment: Вы то, что видите он больше к осязаемым вещам или к теории ближе? Фантазер он? Он загорится от управления роботом или больше кайф словит от решения сложной мат. задачи? Мы можем рассуждать сколько угодно, но дети, блин, все же дети. Может и переспективней в биг дату, но если перегорит? Поймет, что ошибся через пару лет? Только что парень чувствует. Сложно вам, мойо первый определился, ошибся и пошел в другую сферу, такое тоже может быть. Только точно убейте вопрос, а то потом не оберемся. Чуть анархии не помешает)

Comment: Надо смотреть на фундаментальные дисциплины. Программирование само по себе можно освоить самостоятельно. А вот методы которые лежат в основе и позволяют решать действительно интересные задачи трудно самому постичь. Мехмат даст лучшую базу чем кибернетика (я сам математик).

Answer (score 4):

ИМХО, выбор вуза для дальнейшей карьеры совершенно иррелевантен. Я учился сначала на физико-химика, потом на физика-теоретика, а программирование изучал по книгам и методом тыка. В результате уже 23 года за клавиатурой.

Мало того, я ещё и в преподаватели для программистов просквозил. Преподавал формальные методы и верификацию, криптографию и блокчейн.Всё это выучил самостоятельно. Преподавал в МГУ, МФТИ, Бауманке, ВШЭ - самый фарш, так сказать. По опыту взаимодействия со студентами могу сказать, что на программиста невозможно выучить, можно только выучиться.

Из совсем свежего опыта. У моей одноклассницы сын за год самостоятельно освоил Python по книгам и видеолекциям. Этим летом начал в Питере работать, за две недели продвинулся с junior до middle, без всякого профильного образования.

Поэтому выбирайте тот вуз, где народ повеселее и аудитории посимпатичнее. Ну и чтоб милых студенток побольше. И чтоб всё свободное от лекций время ботал книжки. Тогда точно выйдет толк.

Всё вышенаписанное есть сугубое имхо кандидата физ-мат наук, в настоящее время подвизающегося CTO стартапа в Южной Корее, где зарабатывает столько денег, что жена собирается покупать домик на Балтийском побережье, затарившись несколькими квартирами в Москве.

Comment: С милыми студентками сложно ботать) Если только они не такие же)

Comment: @Dmitry ну да, я учился вообще без девушек в группе. Оно, конечно, способствовало :)))

Answer (score 3):

ИИ и Big Data - это всего лишь термины, в которые можно вложить довольно разное содержание. Вроде бы понятие ИИ шире, но что под ним понимают в конкретном ВУЗ-е - это ещё вопрос. И того и другого хватит на весь период учёбы и ещё останется полно чего изучать. В настоящее время машинное обучение/ИИ/Big Data применяются в таком количестве разнообразных областей, что и за всю жизнь не изучить. В каждой предметной области свои математические модели, свои способы сбора и обработки данных, свои инженерные решения. Думаю, базу даст любой из институтов, а куда развиваться дальше это надо будет после решать. Возможно, в процессе учёбы настанет понимание, какая из областей интереснее для изучения, главное чтобы там дали хотя бы общее представление о разных областях применения. Ну и сейчас богатые возможности для самостоятельного изучения чего угодно - видео-уроки на ютьюбе, интерактивные уроки и проверка заданий, не говоря уже о любой документации. Я оканчивал когда-то давно мехмат, но программирование, а недавно и Data Science изучал сугубо самостоятельно, институт мне почти ничего не дал по моей профессии программиста. Ну, забавно, конечно, было писать в универе задачки на Паскале и Фортране, но уже тогда это никому на реальном производстве не было нужно, всё, что реально было потом нужно по работе, я изучал сам. Возможно, сейчас в ВУЗ-ах и дают что-то современное и полезное, но надо быть готовым к тому, что придётся много учиться самостоятельно, чтобы получить реально востребованные работодателями знания.